# how to understand logcat error java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw bitmap too big (109320552bytes)

Tags: android

I am creating an application, after I tried it on the emulator there was no problem, but when the application was tried on an Android device the application failed when I successfully logged in

Can someone help me ?
Maybe what advice to do

this is logcat

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: elnusa.co.smart, PID: 5859
java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(109320552bytes) bitmap.
    at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:260)
    at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1415)
    at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:528)
    at android.view.View.getDrawableRenderNode(View.java:17428)
    at android.view.View.drawBackground(View.java:17364)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17176)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16167)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16951)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView.drawChild(FragmentContainerView.java:235)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView.dispatchDraw(FragmentContainerView.java:223)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16162)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16951)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.dispatchDraw(ConstraintLayout.java:1975)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16162)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16951)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16162)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16951)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16162)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16951)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16162)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16951)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16162)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16951)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17188)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:753)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16167)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:648)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:654)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:762)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2800)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2608)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2215)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6337)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

This is the code on the login page

```
    package elnusa.co.smart;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;

import elnusa.co.smart.model.RequestHandler;
import elnusa.co.smart.model.SharedPrefManager;
import elnusa.co.smart.model.URLs;
import elnusa.co.smart.model.User;


public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ConnectivityManager conMgr;
    EditText editTextUsername, editTextPassword;
    Button login;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        if (SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).isLoggedIn()) {
            finish();
            User user = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getUser();
            if(user.getLevel().equals("admin")){
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MenuAdminActivity.class));
            return;}
            else{
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MenuActivity.class));
                return;
            }
        }

        editTextUsername = findViewById(R.id.Login_txt_email);
        editTextPassword = findViewById(R.id.Login_txt_password);


        //if user presses on login
        //calling the method login
        login=findViewById(R.id.Login_btn_login);
        login.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (activeNetwork != null) {
                // connected to the internet
                if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                    userLogin();
                } else if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                    userLogin();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet Connection",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        });


    }

    private void userLogin() {
        //first getting the values
        final String username = editTextUsername.getText().toString();
        final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

        //validating inputs
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(username)) {
            editTextUsername.setError("Please enter your username");
            editTextUsername.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            editTextPassword.setError("Please enter your password");
            editTextPassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        //if everything is fine

        class UserLogin extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

            ProgressBar progressBar;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBarLogin);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                try {
                    //converting response to json object
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);

                    //if no error in response
                    if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        //getting the user from the response
                        JSONObject userJson = obj.getJSONObject("user");

                        //creating a new user object
                        User user = new User(
                                userJson.getInt("id"),
                                userJson.getString("username"),
                                userJson.getString("email"),
                                userJson.getString("level"),
                                userJson.getString("nama"),
                                userJson.getString("jenis_kelamin"),
                                userJson.getString("no_hp"),
                                userJson.getString("sertifikat"),
                                userJson.getString("no_kta"),
                                userJson.getString("no_reg"),
                                userJson.getString("masa_berlaku"),
                                userJson.getString("alamat"),
                                userJson.getString("agama"),
                                userJson.getString("tempat_lahir"),
                                userJson.getString("tgl_lahir"),
                                userJson.getString("area"),
                                userJson.getString("letak_gbr"),
                                userJson.getString("nama_gbr")
                        );
                        if (userJson.getString("level").equals("admin")) {
                            //storing the user in shared preferences
                            SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).userLogin(user);

                            //starting the profile activity
                            finish();
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MenuAdminActivity.class));
                        }else {
                            //storing the user in shared preferences
                            SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).userLogin(user);

                            //starting the profile activity
                            finish();
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MenuActivity.class));
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid username or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                //creating request handler object
                RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler();

                //creating request parameters
                HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("username", username);
                params.put("password", password);

                //returing the response
                return requestHandler.sendPostRequest(URLs.URL_LOGIN, params);
            }
        }

        UserLogin ul = new UserLogin();
        ul.execute();
    }
}
```

this is the code after successful login

```
    package elnusa.co.smart;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

import elnusa.co.smart.model.SharedPrefManager;

public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
        if (!SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).isLoggedIn()) {
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
        }
        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_datadiri, R.id.navigation_menu, R.id.navigation_logout)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);


        findViewById(R.id.navigation_logout).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
                SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).logout();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem with code, but a problem with a size of your bitmap image:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(109320552bytes) bitmap.
Open properties of your Android emulator. Press All Properties, and increase virtual memory and the disk space, f.e., to 2-3 Gb. Run project again.